# How can I change what's on the Places Bar of a common dialog box?

Tags: delphi, common-dialog

How can I add an item to the Places Bar on the left side of a standard file dialog box (TOpenDialog), where there are usually "Desktop", "My Computer", "My Documents", "My Network", etc.?

Still a question how therefrom to clean standard buttons and whether it is possible to make it?

[image: picture of a Windows XP open dialog]

Comment: Oh, sorry. Not a duplicate. You are talking about the links to the left. You are aware of the fact that these links have been removed in Windows Vista and Windows 7, right?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx#S2 Be sure to continue reading through the next section.

Comment: I cleaned up your main question, but I have no idea what you're trying to say in the second paragraph. Please clarify.

Comment: The standard buttons look quite clean to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article by Fikret Hasovic here:
http://fhasovic.blogspot.com/2004/09/custom-places-bar.html
that links to the MSDN article on it, and he provides Delphi code to download.

Comment: Nothing might work on Windows 7. As Andreas said in his comment, the Places Bar has been removed from Vista and Windows 7. They could have removed support for it completely. You might have to check for Windows 7 and if so, use the Windows 7 File Dialog Box instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268178/how-to-check-in-delphi-the-os-version-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2

Comment: On a Win7 installation patched to 2020-01-02 the left "places" pane can still be configured flawlessly. [Archive.org copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20070825003235/http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/03/03/CuttingEdge/default.aspx) of the original article.