# How to get the Windows version is Vista and up versus XP on Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

Is there any way to know which verion of Windows we are working on?

I need to set image to TBitButton in Windows XP and no image in Windows7. It should be done automatically.

Comment: You need to make a Windows api call, specifically, call GetVersionEx. A quick search turns up this tutorial on calling windows api from delphi: http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorConUK97/WinAPI/Api.htm

Comment: @VoidStar: No, you don't. :) Delphi does this automatically - there are several variables set in the `SysUtils` unit that you can read for various parts of the version number. You only need `GetVersionEx` if you're looking for more details like what edition (Professional, Home, Server, etc.) you're using.

Comment: The other answer (by Ken) tells you how to know the difference between Windows Vista and later, and Windows 7.  To know exactly what version of windows, and to differentiate between server versions and desktop versions, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124/how-to-detect-true-windows-version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the `SysUtils.Win32MajorVersion` (in Delphi 7, you'll need to add `SysUtils` to your `uses` clause if it's not there already - later versions add it automatically). The easiest way is to assign the `Glyph` as usual in the IDE, and clear it if you're running on Vista or higher:

```
if SysUtils.Win32MajorVersion >= 6 then // Windows Vista or higher
  BitBtn1.Glyph := nil;
```

For more info on detecting specific Windows editions and versions, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268178/how-to-check-in-delphi-the-os-version-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2). It hasn't been updated for the latest Windows versions and editions, but it'll get you started. You can also search SO for `[delphi] GetVersionEx` to see other examples.

Comment: This is the way to detect Vista/2008 and up. Beware of the related function CheckWin32Version because in D6 at least it was simply incorrect. It has been fixed, but I'm not sure about D7.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a little project of mine - a drop-in component which provides info of the operating system - even preview it in design-time...

```
unit JDOSInfo;

interface

uses
  Classes, Windows, SysUtils, StrUtils, Forms, Registry;

type
  TJDOSInfo = class(TComponent)
  private
    fReg: TRegistry;
    fKey: String;
    fMinor: Integer;
    fMajor: Integer;
    fBuild: Integer;
    fPlatform: Integer;
    fIsServer: Bool;
    fIs64bit: Bool;
    fProductName: String;
    function GetProductName: String;
    procedure SetProductName(Value: String);
    procedure SetMajor(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetMinor(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetBuild(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetPlatform(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetIs64Bit(const Value: Bool);
    procedure SetIsServer(const Value: Bool);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Major: Integer read fMajor write SetMajor;
    property Minor: Integer read fMinor write SetMinor;
    property Build: Integer read fBuild write SetBuild;
    property Platf: Integer read fPlatform write SetPlatform;
    property ProductName: String read GetProductName write SetProductName;
    property IsServer: Bool read fIsServer write SetIsServer;
    property Is64Bit: Bool read fIs64bit write SetIs64Bit;
  end;

function IsWOW64: Boolean; 
function GetOSInfo: TOSVersionInfo;


procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('JD Custom', [TJDOSInfo]);
end;

function GetOSInfo: TOSVersionInfo;
begin
  FillChar(Result, SizeOf(Result), 0);
  Result.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(Result);
  if not GetVersionEx(Result) then
    raise Exception.Create('Error calling GetVersionEx');
end;

function IsWOW64: Boolean;
type
  TIsWow64Process = function( // Type of IsWow64Process API fn
    Handle: THandle;
    var Res: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  IsWow64Result: BOOL;              // result from IsWow64Process
  IsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;  // IsWow64Process fn reference
begin
  // Try to load required function from kernel32
  IsWow64Process:= GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32'),'IsWow64Process');
  if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then
  begin
    // Function is implemented: call it
    if not IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64Result) then
      raise Exception.Create('Bad process handle');
    // Return result of function
    Result := IsWow64Result;
  end else
    // Function not implemented: can't be running on Wow64
    Result:= False;
end;

constructor TJDOSInfo.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  Info: TOSVersionInfo;
  Str: String;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  fReg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  fReg.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  fKey:= 'Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion';  
  fReg.OpenKey(fKey, False);
  Info:= GetOSInfo;
  fMajor:= Info.dwMajorVersion;
  fMinor:= Info.dwMinorVersion;
  fBuild:= Info.dwBuildNumber;
  fIsServer:= False;
  fIs64bit:= False;
  fPlatform:= Info.dwPlatformId;
  if fMajor >= 5 then begin
    //After 2000
    if fReg.ValueExists('ProductName') then
      Str:= fReg.ReadString('ProductName')
    else begin
      Str:= 'Unknown OS: '+IntToStr(fMajor)+'.'+IntToStr(fMinor)+'.'+
        IntToStr(fBuild)+'.'+IntToStr(fPlatform);
    end;      
    if fReg.ValueExists('InstallationType') then begin
      if UpperCase(fReg.ReadString('InstallationType')) = 'SERVER' then
        fIsServer:= True;
    end;
    fIs64bit:= IsWOW64;
    if fIs64bit then
      Str:= Str + ' 64 Bit';
  end else begin
    //Before 2000
    case fMajor of
      4: begin
        case fMinor of
          0: Str:= 'Windows 95';
          10: Str:= 'Windows 98';
          90: Str:= 'Windows ME';
        end;
      end;
      else begin
        Str:= 'Older than 95';
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Self.fProductName:= Str;
end;

destructor TJDOSInfo.Destroy;
begin
  if assigned(fReg) then begin
    if fReg.Active then
      fReg.CloseKey;
    fReg.Free;
  end;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TJDOSInfo.GetProductName: String;
begin
  Result:= Self.fProductName;
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetProductName(Value: String);
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetMinor(Value: Integer); 
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetMajor(Value: Integer); 
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetBuild(Value: Integer);  
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetPlatform(Value: Integer); 
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetIs64Bit(const Value: Bool);
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

procedure TJDOSInfo.SetIsServer(const Value: Bool);
begin
  //Do Nothing Here!
end;

end.
```

Comment: Fails to detect NT. This code feels odd. If Assigned then Free? Just call Free. What are the empty property setters for?

Comment: Not sure about the NT not detecting, original code was bits and pieces of other code I found. I always, and I mean ALWAYS check if things are created before freeing them, just in case (anything to prevent an access violation). Empty property setters are to allow showing the properties in design-time. At least in Delphi 7, you're not able to publish read-only properties. I believe other later versions do allow it, but this is a read-only trick.

Comment: Plus, I never finished it, set it aside for a while, but it works enough to do what what Rakesh needs to do.

Comment: You can call `Free` on a nil object reference. So, in fact, never check if something is assigned before calling `Free`.

Comment: Normally I would argue things like this, but first of all it's not a big deal, second of all it's not related, and third of all it makes no sense anyway because I'm reading from fReg before I even do that check...

Comment: Well, you have a chance to learn something here. In fact the bug is that method call on fReg in the destructor. The `if Assigned(fReg)` check is needed around that code, but is most definitely not needed and poor style when just calling `Free`.

Comment: Yes, I just acknowledged that bug in my last comment. Please let me make it a little more clear: I made this component over a year ago, rarely used it, never finished it, and never intended for it to be any final product. Actually I forgot it wasn't finished. I just copied/pasted the code here to demonstrate for the question. Sorry it's not perfect, but it works. Thanks for pointing out the flaws, I'll fix them for the future.

Comment: ** Modified destructor method above - Although practically harmless, that was rather a dumb mistake of mine, reminds me that's how I used to code over a year ago, and how much I've learned since then.