# Windows Version Using OSVERSIONINFOEX

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to determine Windows Version using OSVERSIONINFOEX in Delphi XE2 as tutorial described in [How to check in delphi the OS version? Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268178/how-to-check-in-delphi-the-os-version-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2) I have defined the following codes :

```
unit ApplicationWizard01;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Registry;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    BitBtn01: TBitBtn;
    Memo01: TMemo;
    procedure BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

_OSVERSIONINFOEX : record
    dwOSVersionInfoSize : DWORD;
    dwMajorVersion      : DWORD;
    dwMinorVersion      : DWORD;
    dwBuildNumber       : DWORD;
    dwPlatformId        : DWORD;
    szCSDVersion        : array[0..127] of AnsiChar;
    wServicePackMajor   : WORD;
    wServicePackMinor   : WORD;
    wSuiteMask          : WORD;
    wProductType        : BYTE;
    wReserved           : BYTE;
  end;
  TOSVERSIONINFOEX : _OSVERSIONINFOEX;

  function GetVersionExA(var lpVersionInformation: TOSVersionInfoEX): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32;

const
  VER_NT_WORKSTATION    :Integer = 1;
  VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE  :Integer = 2;
  VER_NT_SERVER         :Integer = 3;
  VER_SUITE_DATACENTER  :Integer = 128;
  VER_SUITE_PERSONAL    :Integer = 512;

const
  PRODUCT_BUSINESS                      = $00000006; {Business Edition}
  PRODUCT_BUSINESS_N                    = $00000010; {Business Edition}
  PRODUCT_CLUSTER_SERVER                = $00000012; {Cluster Server Edition}
  PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER             = $00000008; {Server Datacenter Edition (Full Installation)}
  PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE        = $0000000C; {Server Datacenter Edition (Core Installation)}
  PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE                    = $00000004; {Enterprise Edition}
  PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_N                  = $0000001B; {Enterprise Edition}
  PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER             = $0000000A; {Server Enterprise Edition (Full Installation)}
  PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE        = $0000000E; {Server Enterprise Edition (Core Installation)}
  PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_IA64        = $0000000F; {Server Enterprise Edition For Itanium Based Systems}
  PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC                    = $00000002; {Home Basic Edition}
  PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC_N                  = $00000005; {Home Basic Edition}
  PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM                  = $00000003; {Home Premium Edition}
  PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_N                = $0000001A; {Home Premium Edition}
  PRODUCT_HOME_SERVER                   = $00000013; {Home Server Edition}
  PRODUCT_SERVER_FOR_SMALLBUSINESS      = $00000018; {Server For Small Business Edition}
  PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER          = $00000009; {Small Business Server}
  PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM  = $00000019; {Small Business Server Premium Edition}
  PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER               = $00000007; {Server Standard Edition (Full Installation)}
  PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE          = $0000000D; {Server Standard Edition (Core Installation)}
  PRODUCT_STARTER                       = $0000000B; {Starter Edition}
  PRODUCT_STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER     = $00000017; {Storage Server Enterprise Edition}
  PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER        = $00000014; {Storage Server Express Edition}
  PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER       = $00000015; {Storage Server Standard Edition}
  PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER      = $00000016; {Storage Server Workgroup Edition}
  PRODUCT_UNDEFINED                     = $00000000; {An Unknown Product}
  PRODUCT_ULTIMATE                      = $00000001; {Ultimate Edition}
  PRODUCT_ULTIMATE_N                    = $0000001C; {Ultimate Edition}
  PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER                    = $00000011; {Web Server Edition}
  PRODUCT_UNLICENSED                    = $ABCDABCD; {Unlicensed Product}




implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
{$EXTERNALSYM GetProductInfo}
  GetProductInfo: function (dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion,
                            dwSpMajorVersion, dwSpMinorVersion: DWORD;
                            var pdwReturnedProductType: DWORD): BOOL stdcall = NIL;

function GetOSInfo: string;
var
  NTBres, BRes: Boolean;
  OSVI: TOSVERSIONINFO;
  OSVI_NT: TOSVERSIONINFOEX;
  tmpStr: string;
  dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion,
  dwSpMajorVersion, dwSpMinorVersion,
  pdwReturnedProductType : DWORD;
begin
  Result := 'Error';
  NTBRes := FALSE;
  try
    OSVI_NT.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVERSIONINFOEX);
    NTBRes := GetVersionExA(OSVI_NT);
    OSVI.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo);
    BRes := GetVersionEx(OSVI);
  except
    OSVI.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo);
    BRes := GetVersionEx(OSVI);
  end;
  if (not BRes) and (not NTBres) then
    Exit;
  Move( OSVI, OSVI_NT, SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo) );

  case OSVI_NT.dwPlatformId of
     VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT:
       begin
         if OSVI_NT.dwMajorVersion <= 4 then
           Result := 'Windows NT ';
         if (OSVI_NT.dwMajorVersion = 5) and (OSVI_NT.dwMinorVersion = 0) then
           Result := 'Windows 2000 ';
         if  (OSVI_NT.dwMajorVersion = 5) and (OSVI_NT.dwMinorVersion = 1) then
           Result := 'Windows XP ';
         if (OSVI_NT.dwMajorVersion = 6) and (OSVI_NT.dwMinorVersion = 0) then
         begin
           Result := 'Windows Vista ';
           if Assigned(GetProductInfo) then
           begin
             GetProductInfo( dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion,
                             dwSpMajorVersion, dwSpMinorVersion,
                             pdwReturnedProductType );
             case pdwReturnedProductType of
               PRODUCT_BUSINESS:
                 tmpStr := 'Business Edition';
               PRODUCT_BUSINESS_N:
                 tmpStr := 'Business Edition';
               PRODUCT_CLUSTER_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Cluster Server Edition';
               PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Datacenter Edition (full installation)';
               PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Datacenter Edition (core installation)';
               PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE:
                 tmpStr := 'Enterprise Edition';
               PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_N:
                 tmpStr := 'Enterprise Edition';
               PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Enterprise Edition (full installation)';
               PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Enterprise Edition (core installation)';
               PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_IA64:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Enterprise Edition for Itanium-based Systems';
               PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC:
                 tmpStr := 'Home Basic Edition';
               PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC_N:
                 tmpStr := 'Home Basic Edition';
               PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM:
                 tmpStr := 'Home Premium Edition';
               PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_N:
                 tmpStr := 'Home Premium Edition';
               PRODUCT_HOME_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Home Server Edition';
               PRODUCT_SERVER_FOR_SMALLBUSINESS:
                 tmpStr := 'Server for Small Business Edition';
               PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Small Business Server';
               PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM:
                 tmpStr := 'Small Business Server Premium Edition';
               PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Standard Edition (full installation)';
               PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE:
                 tmpStr := 'Server Standard Edition (core installation)';
               PRODUCT_STARTER:
                 tmpStr := 'Starter Edition';
               PRODUCT_STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Storage Server Enterprise Edition';
               PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Storage Server Express Edition';
               PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Storage Server Standard Edition';
               PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Storage Server Workgroup Edition';
               PRODUCT_UNDEFINED:
                 tmpStr := 'An unknown product';
               PRODUCT_ULTIMATE:
                 tmpStr := 'Ultimate Edition';
               PRODUCT_ULTIMATE_N:
                 tmpStr := 'Ultimate Edition';
               PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER:
                 tmpStr := 'Web Server Edition';
               PRODUCT_UNLICENSED:
                 tmpStr := 'Unlicensed product'
             else
               tmpStr := '';
             end;{ pdwReturnedProductType }
             Result := Result + tmpStr;
             NTBRes := FALSE;
           end;{ GetProductInfo<>NIL }
         end;{ Vista }
         if NTBres then
         begin
           if OSVI_NT.wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION then
           begin
             if OSVI_NT.wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION then
             begin
               case OSVI_NT.wSuiteMask of
                 512: Result := Result + 'Personal';
                 768: Result := Result + 'Home Premium';
               else
                 Result := Result + 'Professional';
               end;
             end
             else if OSVI_NT.wProductType = VER_NT_SERVER then
             begin
               if OSVI_NT.wSuiteMask = VER_SUITE_DATACENTER then
                 Result := Result + 'DataCenter Server'
               else if OSVI_NT.wSuiteMask = VER_SUITE_ENTERPRISE then
                 Result :=  Result + 'Advanced Server'
               else
                 Result := Result + 'Server';
             end;
           end{ wProductType=VER_NT_WORKSTATION }
           else
           begin
             with TRegistry.Create do
               try
                 RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
                 if OpenKeyReadOnly('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions') then
                   try
                     tmpStr := UpperCase(ReadString('ProductType'));
                     if tmpStr = 'WINNT' then
                       Result := Result + 'Workstation';
                     if tmpStr = 'SERVERNT' then
                       Result := Result + 'Server';
                   finally
                     CloseKey;
                   end;
               finally
                 Free;
               end;
             end;{ wProductType<>VER_NT_WORKSTATION }
           end;{ NTBRes }
         end;{ VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT }
     VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS:
       begin
         if (OSVI.dwMajorVersion = 4) and (OSVI.dwMinorVersion = 0) then
         begin
           Result := 'Windows 95 ';
           if OSVI.szCSDVersion[1] = 'C' then
             Result := Result + 'OSR2';
         end;
         if (OSVI.dwMajorVersion = 4) and (OSVI.dwMinorVersion = 10) then
         begin
           Result := 'Windows 98 ';
           if OSVI.szCSDVersion[1] = 'A' then
             Result := Result + 'SE';
         end;
         if (OSVI.dwMajorVersion = 4) and (OSVI.dwMinorVersion = 90) then
           Result := 'Windows Me';
       end;{ VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS }
     VER_PLATFORM_WIN32s:
       Result := 'Microsoft Win32s';
  else
    Result := 'Unknown';
  end;{ OSVI_NT.dwPlatformId }
end;{ GetOSInfo }

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;

initialization
   @GetProductInfo := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('KERNEL32.DLL'),
                                     'GetProductInfo');

end.
```

But I am getting a large numbers of error as follows :

```
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(36): E2007 Constant or type identifier expected
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(38): E2005 'TOSVERSIONINFOEX' is not a type identifier
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(96): E2007 Constant or type identifier expected
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(105): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(117): E2029 'OF' expected but identifier 'dwPlatformId' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(117): E2029 ',' or ':' expected but 'OF' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(120): E2029 'THEN' expected but identifier 'dwMajorVersion' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(122): E2029 ')' expected but identifier 'dwMajorVersion' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(124): E2029 ')' expected but identifier 'dwMajorVersion' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(126): E2029 ')' expected but identifier 'dwMajorVersion' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(204): E2029 'THEN' expected but identifier 'wProductType' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(206): E2029 'THEN' expected but identifier 'wProductType' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(208): E2029 'OF' expected but identifier 'wSuiteMask' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(208): E2029 ',' or ':' expected but 'OF' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(215): E2029 'THEN' expected but identifier 'wProductType' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(217): E2029 'THEN' expected but identifier 'wSuiteMask' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(219): E2029 'THEN' expected but identifier 'wSuiteMask' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(246): E2029 ':=' expected but ':' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(247): E2029 Expression expected but 'BEGIN' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(263): E2029 ':=' expected but ':' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(264): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'string'
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(270): E2070 Unknown directive: 'TMainForm'
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(275): E2029 Statement expected but 'INITIALIZATION' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(275): E2029 ';' expected but 'INITIALIZATION' found
[DCC Error] ApplicationWizard01.pas(13): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TMainForm.BitBtn01Click'
[DCC Fatal Error] ApplicationWizard.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'ApplicationWizard01.pas'
```

Comment: You're missing `type` keyword before the line with `_OSVERSIONINFOEX`.

Comment: I have added the "type" but the error is in "_OSVERSIONINFOEX : record" line as "E2029 '=' expected but ':' found" and "szCSDVersion: array[0..127] of AnsiChar;" line as "E2029 '=' expected but ':' found". Please help me.

Comment: Ah, I see. You just copied that wrong somehow. It doesn't matter, you don't need all those types and constant as you have them already defined in the `Winapi.Windows.pas` unit.

Comment: In other words, "I copied and pasted a bunch of code without really understanding what any of it meant, and when it didn't compile, I tried some random edits to make the errors I didn't want to understand go away; use my edited code to guess my original mistake." Voting to close as **too localized**.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you did not copy the code from @Ken's answer. There's no point in us trying to debug the transcription errors that you made. The correct solution is to use the code from the answer correctly. Since @Ken gave you a complete unit, just use that. Make sure you use the clipboard. Select the entire unit and paste it into an empty editor window. Then save it to a file named `GetWinVersionInfo.pas`.

If you need to edit that code then I would probably remove all the declarations that can now be found in the Windows unit. It avoids confusion having only the one copy of these things. For example the types and constants can, I think, all be removed.

Comment: I think you are telling that like "TOSVersion" is translated in "System.SysUtils" , "TOSVersionInfoEx" is translated in "Winapi.Windows". If so how to implement it.

Comment: Yes that is right. Could you tell us what you want to use this code for?

Comment: I want this code for firstly showing windows version more specifically. Secondly if the OS is the Vista Ultimate or Seven Ultimate the only some buttons will be enabled and my program will run.

Comment: I think "TOSVersion" does not specify Windows Edition, it can only be done using "TOSVersionInfoEx" only. I am not desperate to use the out dated code. Updated codes are always wellcomed.

Comment: Another problem is that "TOSVersion.Name" only returns "Windows" not "Windows 8" in Windows 8 environment.

Comment: The edition is found by calling `GetProductInfo`

Comment: Second Paragraph of which post?

Comment: Just use the clipboard.

Comment: I don't understand. Please provide so example.

Comment: The example is at the other answer to which you linked. You made a mistake when copy/pasting the code. The solution is to do that simple clipboard operation correctly.

Comment: Is there any sample code is available using "GetProductInfo". If so please share.

Comment: The code that you linked to does exactly that!