# Resource Saving In System Directory

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 Project to save one DLL File (File Name = MyFile.dll) from Resource (Resource Name = DynamicLlinkLibraryWin32) in Windows System Directory. I have defined the following codes:

```
function GetSysDir: string;
var
  SystemDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetSystemDirectory(SystemDirectory, MAX_PATH - 2);
  SetLength(Result, StrLen(SystemDirectory));
  Result := SystemDirectory;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
  ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01 : string;
begin
  ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01 := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetSysDir);
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DynamicLlinkLibraryWin32', RT_RCDATA); {Resource Name=DynamicLlinkLibraryWin32}
  try
    ResStream.SaveToFile('ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01\MyFile.dll'); {File Name=MyFile.dll}
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

At runtime I am getting error telling that "The system can not find the path specified". Why?

Comment: Are you aware that 1. You need to elevate to write there, and 2. Apps must not write there since the system directory is private to the system. So, once you fix this, your app will be breaking the rules.

Comment: Did you elevate ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

Comment: Yes Manifest is "AsAdministrator".

Comment: You don't seem to use GetSysResult anywhere. Copiler should give you warning that you never sue value of `ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01`.
Read what compiler warning says to you, they gove you the hints you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not formatting the destination filename correctly, and you are not taking WOW64 into account at all when determining the correct System folder path.  When running under the WOW64 emulator, you have to use the `sysnative` alias to access the 64-bit System folder from a 32-bit process.  In a 32-bit process on a 32-bit system, and a 64-bit process on a 64-bit system, `GetSystemDirectory()` will return the correct path instead.  Use `IsWow64Process()` to detect whether your 32-bit app is running under WOW64 or not.

Try this instead:

```
function GetSysDir: string;
var
  Buf: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  Len: UINT;
  S: String;
  {$IFNDEF WIN64}
  IsWow64: BOOL;
  {$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFNDEF WIN64}
  IsWow64 := FALSE;
  if not IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), @IsWow64) then RaoseLastOSError;
  if IsWow64 then
  begin
    Len := GetWindowsDirectory(Buf, MAX_PATH);
    if Len = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
    SetString(S, Buf, Len);
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(S) + 'Sysnative\';
    Exit;
  end;
  {$ENDIF}
  Len := GetSystemDirectory(Buf, MAX_PATH);
  if Len = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  SetString(S, Buf, Len);
  Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(S);
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DynamicLlinkLibraryWin32', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    ResStream.SaveToFile(GetSysDir + 'MyFile.dll');
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Rubi What's weird about all this, is that the points that Remy is addressing are all based off the comments to my answer. So your accept is based on the fact that Remy addressed all the other issues, the ones that were not in the question. At the very least you ought to edit the question to match the answer!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: perhaps, but they were in your comments, not your answer, and I provided working code and you did not. And I did address everything that was in Rubi's question.

Comment: @Remy Your answer is fine. It's just a little bit out of place next to the question. Which doesn't talk about wow64 at all. What happens next is that Rubi asks something more in comments, somebody else answers, and that answer gets accepted. And so on. It's not even a chameleon question because the question remains unchanged. And I certainly did provide working code in my answer to the question that was asked. I'm hoping that we can teach Rubi to work things out for himself. That hope is probably forlorn.

Comment: The reason why there's no sysnative in my answer is because it's not in the question. I'm following the Q&A principle. If the question had been edited to discuss WOW64, or a new question asked, then answers would fit.

Answer (score 3):

You are saving  to  a file named:

```
'ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01\MyFile.dll'
```

So the system treats this as a relative path and it seems that there is no directory named `'ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01'` contained in the working directory.

Clearly you meant to write:

```
ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01+'\MyFile.dll'
```

Comment: Yes. I want to write **ResourceSavingPathAndFileName01+'\MyFile.dll'**. Thanks a lot. Your Syntax is working properly. But the problem is that it always detects **SysWOW64** as system directory in case Win64Bit OS. So I am trying to **GetWinDir** Function the adding **\System32**. Thanks again.

Comment: That won't change things one little bit. The file system redirector will still put it in SysWOW64. You need to write to `C:\Windows\Sysnative` if you want the 64 bit system directory. If the DLL is 32 bit, then it needs to go in the 32 bit system directory if you want anything to be able to find it. However, you should not write to the system directory at all. Why on earth are you doing that?

Comment: My DLL file is 64Bit so it always gets saved in **SysWOW64** directory in case Win64Bit OS for both **GetWinDir** Function and **GetSysDir** Function. My requirement is to save in **System32** directory only. Please help me. I am unable to do.

Comment: Read my comment! Save it to sysnative. Read about the file system redirector. I can do a Google search for you and give you think link there. Would you like me to do that for you?

Comment: I already did. Save it to `C:\Windows\Sysnative`. I will **not** perform a websearch for "File system redirector" for you.

Comment: @RubiHalder Did you have a problem with my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everybody. I have it in my way because I am a beginner and I am not comfortable to **$IfNDef Compiler Directive**. I have used **Ken Whites's Code** ([How to check in delphi the OS version? Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268178/how-to-check-in-delphi-the-os-version-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2)) for Windows detection and **Remy Lebeau Examples** ([Resource Saving In System Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998542/resource-saving-in-system-directory/16003247#16003247)). It works perfectly in **Delphi XE2**. My code is as follows :

```
unit ApplicationWizard01;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    BitBtn01: TBitBtn;
    procedure BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

var
  GetNativeSystemInfo: function(var SysInfo: TSystemInfo): BOOL stdcall = nil;
var
  GetProductInfo: function (dwOSMajorVersion, dwOSMinorVersion,
                            dwSpMajorVersion, dwSpMinorVersion: DWORD;
                            var pdwReturnedProductType: DWORD): BOOL stdcall = nil;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetSysDir: string;
var
  SystemDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetSystemDirectory(SystemDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
  SetLength(Result, StrLen(SystemDirectory));
  Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SystemDirectory);
end;

function GetSysNativeDir: string;
var
  WindowsDirectory: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(WindowsDirectory, MAX_PATH - 1);
   SetLength(Result, StrLen(WindowsDirectory));
   Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(WindowsDirectory)  + 'Sysnative\';
end;

procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NTBres, BRes: Boolean;
  OSVI: TOSVERSIONINFO;
  OSVI_NT: TOSVERSIONINFOEX;
  SI: TSystemInfo;
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
  ResourceSavingPathAndFileName : string;
begin
  NTBRes := false;
  try
    OSVI_NT.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVERSIONINFOEX);
    NTBRes := GetVersionEx(OSVI_NT);
    OSVI.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo);
    BRes := GetVersionEx(OSVI);
  except
    OSVI.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo);
    BRes := GetVersionEx(OSVI);
  end;
  if (not BRes) and (not NTBres) then Exit;
  Move( OSVI, OSVI_NT, SizeOf(TOSVersionInfo) );
  if Assigned(GetNativeSystemInfo) then GetNativeSystemInfo(SI) else GetSystemInfo(SI);
  if (SI.wProcessorArchitecture = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL) then
    begin
      ResourceSavingPathAndFileName := (GetSysDir);
      ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DynamicLlinkLibraryWin32', RT_RCDATA);
      try
        ResStream.SaveToFile(ResourceSavingPathAndFileName + 'FileWin32.dll');
      finally
        ResStream.Free;
      end;
    end
  else if (SI.wProcessorArchitecture = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64) then
    begin
      ResourceSavingPathAndFileName := (GetSysNativeDir);
      ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DynamicLlinkLibraryWin64', RT_RCDATA);
      try
        ResStream.SaveToFile(ResourceSavingPathAndFileName + 'FileWin64.dll');
      finally
        ResStream.Free;
      end;
    end;
  ShowMessage ('Resource Has Been Saved Successfully');
end;

initialization
  @GetProductInfo := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('KERNEL32.DLL'),
                                     'GetProductInfo');

  @GetNativeSystemInfo := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('KERNEL32.DLL'),
                                         'GetNativeSystemInfo');

end.
```