# Windows Forms load on base of Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is possible load a Form on base of windows?

```
if Windows XP load form1
if windows 7 x86 load form2
if windows 7 x64 load form3
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241603/what-is-the-best-way-for-a-winforms-application-to-determine-exactly-which-window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes use [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)

```
System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion
```

See this SO question to find out how to interpret the results: [How to translate MS Windows OS version numbers into product names in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545666/how-to-translate-ms-windows-os-version-numbers-into-product-names-in-net) together with this one: [How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net).

Then just load the appropriate version of the form.

Comment: Is it possible to get all possible result's from System.Enviroment.OSVersion ?

Comment: No it is not. You have to work out the bittyness too. It's just a couple of functions, and you can hide them in a helper class.