# Environment Variable to determine the OS type (Windows XP, Windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, environment-variables

I want to differentiate between Windows XP and Windows 7 in a XML file. Thought i will use an environment variable for it inside the XML.

However I could not find any system environment variable defined in windows that gives this information.

I see the %OSTYPE% variable but it is only available in Windows 7. It is not defined in XP.

Is there anyway i could do this?

Note that i would like a solution which purely depends on system environment variables. I do not want to create new variables based on executing some command, because i want to use this variable in a XML file.

Comment: Possible dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124/how-to-detect-true-windows-version

Comment: @ChrisF, that question actually talks about detecting the Windows version by any available means (mostly by APIs). Not necessarily System Environment Variables.

Comment: Which is why I just commented rather than voting to close. Do any of the answers help at all?

Comment: Actually not. I am inside a XML file and i do not have access to any of the APIs from that file. However, it if were a environment variable, it would just expand itself and i would accomplish what i wanted to do..

Comment: Ah well. There doesn't appear to be an XP specific environment variable (at least that I can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exactly preset environment variables but...

[This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20140623130801/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190899) is from Microsoft and it refers to a program called `gettype.exe`, I don't know if this is a built-in or not. I'm not on Windows to test. Anyway, maybe it helps you.

There's also `ver` which looks built-in - [here's an example script](http://web.archive.org/web/20160306174053/http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0025.html) using that.

Comment: These samples make use of running utility command or programs to determine the type of the OS. I was wondering if it is possible by just using environment variables?

Answer (score 6):

Near as I can tell  the environment variable in XP is "OS".

> OS: Lists the name of the operating system. (Windows XP and Windows 2000 list the operating system as Windows_NT.)

See:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-windows-xps-environment-variables/5986211

Comment: The "OS" environment variable has the value "Windows_NT" on at least the following systems: Windows XP, Windows 2000 and Windows 7.  I don't know about other Windows flavours, but it seems likely to be the same on those as well.  Perhaps someone else could confirm.

Comment: "OS" is "Windows_NT" on Windows 10 and the server operating systems as well. So that's not very helpful unless you're on Windows98 or earlier.