# List of Kernel32.dll versions that ship with various Windows versions?

Tags: windows, kernel32, windowsversion

I'm trying to find out the true Windows version. For some reason my Wise installer sometimes reports the an XP version # on Windows 7.

One solution is to look at the kernel32.dll version as mentioned here:
[How to detect true Windows version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124/how-to-detect-true-windows-version/57156#57156)

I'm trying to find out the corresponding Windows version for various Kernel32.dll versions.

Comment: `For some reason my Wise installer sometimes reports the an XP version # on Windows 7` - it's probably been put into a compatibility mode because it's doing something incorrectly. Why not fix the problem than try to work around it?

Comment: If the user wants to run your installer in XP compat mode, don't try to stop them. Perhaps that's the only way they can get your installer to work.

Comment: @todda - this happens only on a tiny % of Windows 7 computer and I can't figure out why and can't repro it here "in the lab".

Comment: BTW, I'm not certain that the cause is that it's running in XP Compatibility mode. That's just my best guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a list of Kernel32.dll versions for each release of Windows, but from testing (XP SP3, Vista, Windows 7) the Kernel32.dll version # (Major.Minor) is the same as the Windows version.

What I specifically found (for this version of windows, this version of Kernel32.dll)
  * Windows XP (win version 5.1) ,5.1.x
  * Windows Vista (win version 6.0), 6.0.x
  * Windows 7 (Win version 6.1), 6.1.x

This isn't perfect but it's better than any other method as a double check to see if the installer is reporting the wrong windows version #.  (I realize that we should be trying to figure out *why* the installer reports the wrong version but it's only happening in about 1% of cases and I can't repro it, so a Kludge is called for.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some versions and even difference between them:
https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=windows

As you can see, the version numbers aren't always equivalent to OS version, but there are also other differences such as API or even DLL availability (although I would think twice before relying on it).