# Get Win32MajorVersion and Win32MinorVersion correctly in Windows 8.1/10

Tags: winapi, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7 Pro and need to get `Win32MajorVersion` and `Win32MinorVersion`, in order to diferenciate between Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.

After several hours researching (english is not my native language, sorry), I understood that I needed to change the manifest file for supporting Windows 8.1 and 10. Here is what I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="WinApp" version="11.0.2804.9245" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="False"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!-- Windows 10 --> 
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application> 
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

But even after including this manifest, `Win32MajorVersion` and `Win32MinorVersion` still give me wrong information on Windows 8.1 and 10.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

PS. I found other SOF posts with other tecniques for not using the manifest file, like using WMI, the Windows registry, etc., but for my purposes I think the manifest will be the most simple and effective way.

Comment: most simply call `RtlGetVersion` or `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` and not need something hardcode in manifest

Comment: @RbMm please, can you answer with the simplest code example of `RtlGetVersion`, so I can test and accept the answer?

Comment: `RTL_OSVERSIONINFOW ovi = { sizeof(ovi)};
 if (0 <= RtlGetVersion(&ovi)) { DbgPrint("%u.%u\n", ovi.dwMajorVersion, ovi.dwMinorVersion); }`

Comment: I am using Delphi 7, but I think I got a functional code. Must I add it as an observation in the post question? Or must I answer my own question? Despite it worked, I am not sure it is 100% correct.

Comment: question like this (how get os version) already asked here many time. *I am not sure it is 100% correct.* - why ?

Comment: I do not know if I was using the wrong search words, but couldn't find a complete solution (for Delphi 7) anywhere. I will add my solution in a observation, so maybe it help other people. Thank you!

Comment: `ZeroMemory(@OS, SizeOf(OS));` - you not need this (not error but and not need), `OS.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(OS);` is enough, in rest how i can understand delphi - correct

Comment: Yes, I am creating a unit for using these information, and just realized the same. Thank you again!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit the solution into your question. If you've found a solution you'd like to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below intended for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `RbMm` comment and an [aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124/how-to-detect-true-windows-version) from Mr. `Remy Lebeau`, I researched some more and created this solution bellow. Despite it is working (for Delphi 7), maybe requires some improvement. Hope it help other people with same requirements. Thanks!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  _OSVERSIONINFOEXW = record
    dwOSVersionInfoSize: DWORD;
    dwMajorVersion: DWORD;
    dwMinorVersion: DWORD;
    dwBuildNumber: DWORD;
    dwPlatformId: DWORD;
    szCSDVersion: array [0..127] of WCHAR;
    wServicePackMajor: WORD;
    wServicePackMinor: WORD;
    wSuiteMask: WORD;
    wProductType: BYTE;
    wReserved: BYTE;
  end;
  RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW = _OSVERSIONINFOEXW;
  pfnRtlGetVersion = function(var RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW): LongInt; stdcall;
var
  OS: RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW;
  RtlGetVersion: pfnRtlGetVersion;
begin
  @RtlGetVersion := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('ntdll.dll'), 'RtlGetVersion');
  if Assigned(RtlGetVersion) then
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@OS, SizeOf(OS));
    OS.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(OS);
    if (RtlGetVersion(OS) = 0) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('MajorVersion: ' + IntToStr(OS.dwMajorVersion));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('MinorVersion: ' + IntToStr(OS.dwMinorVersion));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('BuildNumber: ' + IntToStr(OS.dwBuildNumber));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ServicePackMajor: ' + IntToStr(OS.wServicePackMajor));
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ServicePackMinor: ' + IntToStr(OS.wServicePackMinor));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(OS.szCSDVersion);
    end;
  end;
end;
```